# Reset USB bus without reboot (MacBook ignores display)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, mouse

I have a MacBook Pro and work with different external monitors. The monitors have a keyboard and a mouse attached. Frequently the MacBook does not recognize the USB devices in the display and the keyboard and mouse do not function. I have to reboot. Is there a way to reset the USB system without rebooting?

Comment: Similar issue here with a Dell P2721Q Dell monitor and a Macbook Air connected via USB-C. Does the display itself connect and show your desktop? Mine does, but the connected USB devices do not function.

Comment: I've had the same problem when connecting/disconnecting my monitor. The `launchctl` commands below didn't work for me, but turning my monitor off and then back on did work (leaving as a comment as I don't have any rep points to answer).

Comment: For those trying to do this with a USB hub: check out [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl), a program that lets you toggle ports on supported USB hubs. From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271282/450147)

Answer (score 27):

You could try restarting the usb daemon in terminal. Like so:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbd; sudo launchctl start com.apple.usbd
```

Comment: You might want to put that into a script.  If you disable USB, then your keyboard/mouse will stop working as they are USB devices.

Comment: @Allan I actually tested and the devices continue to function. Still a script or Automator action with a keyboard shortcut would make it a lot easier to use if it works.

Comment: Wow! My USB to Serial adapters keep freaking out the usb ports until I run out of them and have to restart my mac. This solution worked, I don't have to do restarts any more because of this nonsense!

Comment: Alas this does not seem to do anything - no longer connected devices are still reported as present, and newly connected devices do not enumerate.

Comment: it would be a good idea to define it as an alias in your profile script. i.e `alias resetusb='sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbd; sudo launchctl start com.apple.usbd'`

Comment: This worked greatly for me. And Apple: seriously? Ever heard of a "refresh" button? Smh.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, though I did get USB to work by unplugging the USB-C, (running the above commands - though I'm not sure that was necessary), and re-plugging.  I.e. I didn't need to reboot. Still, would be great to have a solution that doesn't require messing with wires.

Comment: @hepcat72 did you ever find a solution to devices connected to USB C without physically unplugging and plugging back in?

Comment: @Rob - I did not, technically. However, something I did stopped the problem from happening and I'm not sure what it was that brought that about. System update? Monitor setting? System pref setting? Behavior in using the monitor buttons? Wire change? It's been too long ago for me to know what made the difference.

Comment: @hepcat72 thanks, i ended up replacing my usb hub and all fine now. I guess not all usb c hubs are made equal. New one is by Anker.

Comment: works for me. Apple should have a button for it.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, it happens with a thunderbolt Apple display, and a thunderbolt LG display, and it's sometimes fixed after connecting/reconnecting/changing USB ports for the keyboard. On the LG even that did not work, only a complete reboot. I'm googling now for a USB reset solution that does not reboot my Mac.

Found this tool here: http://v6download.touch-base.com/downloads/MacProber/USB_Prober_Mac_OS_X_10.7.3.zip. Still works on Sierra. I will keep this handy on my desktop in case it happens again.