# can i find usb path and save to variable for quick backups?

Tags: mac, backup, bash, path

i would like to add the path to inserted flash drive named backup1 to a variable so i can copy /Documents/dir to this flash drive path in one script without user interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `B=/Volumes/backup1` and then `cp -p /Documents/dir/* $B`.

Comment: now i wanted to eject with the same $B and got umount: unmount(/Volumes/backup1): Operation not permitted

Comment: @scrappy, ask a separate question, but see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271252/disconnect-connect-usb-device-from-command-line first