# Terminal command to "unplug" and replug external monitor

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, resolution, cinema-display

I'm using an old Apple 30" Cinema Display via a series of dongles:

> [Apple Silicon M1 Mac connecting 30" Apple Cinema Display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411391/apple-silicon-m1-mac-connecting-30-apple-cinema-display)

The native resolution is `2560 x 1600` and works great.

It may require to holding <kbd>Option</kbd> when clicking "Scaled" to get that resolution.

Occasionally, after awaking from sleep, the monitor awakens in an ugly pixelated low resolution state. System Preferences shows `1280 x 800` as the max resolution.

At this point I unplug/replug the USB-C cable. The monitor goes back to native resolution after it reconnects.

I want to avoid digging behind my desk to unplug the USB-C / Thunderbolt cable.

Is there a Terminal command I can run to quickly "reconnect" all external displays?

I'm not interested in anything that would require me to shut down the Mac, reset the NVRAM, etc. What I want is a quick software alternative to manually unplugging the monitor.

[image: low res state]

Comment: May be this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173866/how-can-i-set-the-display-settings-using-command-line) can help you

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423571/force-usb-detection-without-unplugging-and-plugging-again-is-there-a-terminal-c

Comment: I have a perhaps similar problem with a 2012 MacBook Pro connected to a monitor via an Apple dual link DVI adaptor. My setup sometimes fails after waking from sleep, showing sync issues on the monitor. I found I am able to fix it by using `shift-ctrl-eject` on the Mac to sleep the display, then wait a few seconds, then wake the display up again by pressing a different key. If this works for you, this would be a simple solution. (But I write as a comment, because I suspect this won't work.)

Comment: (Continued...) One issue will be that there isn't an `eject` key on M1 Macs? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 says the key combination to sleep displays is "Control–Shift–Power button \*"... but "\* Does not apply to the Touch ID sensor", and the meaning of that is unclear to me.

Comment: @Ashley just tested: `Sleep` from the Apple menu and then re-wake did not cause the list to refresh.

Comment: @pkamb I'm mostly using a different setup at the moment and can't quite remember, but I think for me, the Apple menu > Sleep option (which sleeps the entire machine) was slower and less reliable at fixing this issue than the "sleep displays" option which I've tried (badly) to point out. I'd give that a go. In that Apple document I've linked to, search for "Put your displays to sleep" to find the key press combination.

Answer (score 1):

Originally answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271252/disconnect-connect-usb-device-from-command-line) -- This can be done by using [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl), which allows you to toggle and cycle power on individual ports for supported USB hubs.

You can use homebrew to install it as follows:

```
brew tap mvp/uhubctl https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl  
brew install uhubctl
```

Comment: It appears that this only works for the ports on USB hubs? Thanks for the link; will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while selecting "scaled"? This should give you a bigger list of options, which may include the one you want. Even if it does not, switching resolutions might be enough of a reset.

If neither of those work, you might try adding an [EDID](https://www.extron.com/article/uedid) emulator to your dongle chain, giving your monitor a more reliable EDID.

Comment: When in the low-res state, holding option doesn't show the native-res option. I'll try switching res next time it happens to see if that kicks the resolution list. The EDID emulator is an interesting approach...

Comment: Switching resolution (or rotation) does not cause the resolution list to refresh.