# Macbook Air USB ports stop working one after another until none (of the two) remain

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware

I have a 2017 Macbook air that has a nice habit of sequentially disabling USB ports (even while they are not being used). I am forced to restart my machine at random times in order to get them back to working order and it takes quite a while for me to get all the work I had open started again.

This seems to be a common problem, but there is no working solution on this site or any other that does not involve restarting. The closest one I've found is here: [Reset USB bus without reboot (MacBook ignores display)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240250/reset-usb-bus-without-reboot-macbook-ignores-display)

It looked promising, but alas didn't actually work.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem that does not include restarting the computer? Is there a circuit I can reset or service I need to restart?

Thanks!

Comment: two quick questions that you should add to your original question. In the linked question have you tried the terminal command (and if so what were the results). Have you tried starting in Safe mode to disable some (Apple) and all 3rd party drivers?

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks! Yep, I've tried the terminal commands and they run without errors, but don't seem to do anything else. I've tried multiple devices on these ports as well to be sure it wasn't an external problem. I haven't tried starting the system in safe mode as that would be kind of impractical (need some of these drivers for work and the usb problem usually doesn't happen until after a couple days of use).